# How do I make a minimum number of <tr> from an @foreach?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a data set that I need to output to a pdf.  I am building the pdf in a view and then using dompdf to generate.  I am trying to get the pdf to resemble a printed form used for the same data.  I'd like to run one @foreach to create the table rows but have it generate a set number of rows whether there is data or not.

For instance, I'd like to generate 15 rows in the table even if there are only 10 records and complete the table with 5 empty rows.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: count how many you generated, then when the loop ends, if you're short, run another loop to generate the missing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple thing :)

```
<?php $N=0; ?>
@foreach($data AS $row)
<tr>
  <td>{{ ++$N }}</td>
  ...
</tr>
@endforeach

@for($i=1; $i<=15-sizeof($data); $i++)
<tr>
  <td>{{ ++$N }}</td>
  ...
</tr>
@endfor
```

Comment: Slick!  How do I add my index increment into that?  I currently have this - ($data AS $index => $row) and $index +1 in the first col of the rows.  It stays at the value of $extra_rows in the second @for.  I have tried $extra_rows +1 but no dice.  Thanks!

Comment: @maskers seems like You need a counter, so check my updated answer

Comment: Yep.  Guess my counter was inside my @foreach so not reachable.  Great simple answer thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of rows beforehand, one option would be to craft the array properly and then send it to the view.

```
// Assuming that $arr is your array of objects 
if(sizeof($arr) < 15) {
    for($i=0; $i < (15-sizeof($arr)); $i++) {
        $arr[] = new YourObject;
    }
}
// Then return the view with
return view('yourview', ['data' => $arr]);
```

In your view, just use a regular `@foreach`

Option 2:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < max(15,sizeof($arr)); $i++)
    @if ($i < sizeof($arr) )
    // Print your data here.
    @else
    // Print an empty row.
    @endif
@endfor
```

Comment: I like the first option.  Is there any reason why (15-sizeof($arr) does not compute as expected?  My $arr count is 7.  I need to use 18 to get it to render 13 total rows.

Comment: So, let me clarify. your array has 7 objects and you need to render 20 total rows? ( 7 rows and 13 empty rows)

Comment: 7 object 6 empty rows - total 13 rows

Comment: What happens when you use 13 - sizeof($arr) ?

Comment: it only added 2 rows

Comment: Used @num8er's answer. +1 for yours though as it also had me on my way.  Thanks folks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. But I still don't get how sizeof($arr) is 11 if you have added only 7 objects.